# Copying the DLL of the referenced C++ project to output folder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild, dependency-management

It's about Visual C++ 2022.

I have three projects:

- Project1, a native DLL project in C++.
- Project2, a managed assembly project in C++.
- Project3, GUI app written in C#.

Project2 references Project1 and consequently links with Project1.lib. Project2 is referenced by Project3.

When Project3 is built, I need Project1.dll to be copied to the location of Project3.exe together with Project2.dll assembly.

All of the suggestions I was able to find mention using a Post Build event, and that's how it's implemented currently. However, I find this approach extremely fragile, because you need to specify the path to the Project1.dll to copy it to the output folder. And that might change, making the Post Build event fail.

I would rather somehow make the Project1.dll a "Content" of the Project2, then it will be automatically copied together with Project2.dll assembly. But still, there's the task of determining the path to Project1.dll inside Project2.vcxproj. I know, that MSBuild calls GetTargetPath on Project1.vcxproj when resolving references in Project2, but I have no idea currently how to use that.

Comment: ***because you need to specify the path to the Project1.dll to copy it to the output folder. And that might change, making the Post Build event fail.*** Use a relative path instead of an absolute one and keep the projects in the same relative location. I usually create a hierarchy where dependent projects are in a subfolder of the main project.

Comment: An alternate option is to use an environment variable to set the path: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build?view=vs-2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Building on the comment from @drescherjm : Generally, you want a hierarchy with a solution file in a folder and the solution-referenced projects in sub-folders of the folder containing the solution file. Always use relative paths. If the entire solution code tree is moved as a unit, the relative paths will not be broken.